# Improve performance when using Range.Paste

Tags: vb.net, performance, excel, range, vba

This performance issue's driving me crazy :(. 
My purpose is to copy `n` rows and paste it `n` times in the same sheet.

My code looks like this :

```
Public Sub InsertRows(ByVal pCopyFrom As Integer, ByVal pCopyTo As Integer _
                         , ByVal pStart As Integer, ByVal pCount As Integer)
    If pCount <= 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim xlRange1 As Excel.Range
    xlRange1 = _sheet.Range(CStr(pCopyFrom) + ":" + CStr(pCopyTo))

    xlRange1.Copy()

    Dim xlPasteRange As Excel.Range = _sheet.Range(CStr(pStart) + ":" + CStr(pStart + pCount * (pCopyTo - pCopyFrom + 1) - 1))

    xlPasteRange.Insert()

End Sub
```

The problem is this will take up to 10 minutes when I call it like this :

```
InsertRows(8, 9, 10, 13000) -- 13000 is the data source row count
```

Is there any suggestion to make it run faster?

Comment: All those `CStr()` are unnecessary and slow - but as they aren't in a loop that won't make any practical difference.  Two places to start - (1) this isn't valid VBA code, so what is it?  And (2) what formulas do you have in the worksheet?  With just static data this runs in <3s on my (slow) laptop.

Comment: @aucuparia I'm sorry I forgot to mention, this's Vb.Net code, using Excel VBA reference. I've some formula in the sheet, I'm not at the company now so I don't have the file, but it's about 15 columns, and 5-7 columns contain formulas, just the normal formula like "=A1/B1*C1"

Comment: It often helps to disable calculations and display updates at the start of your code (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`)  and restore them when you're done (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`)

Comment: If you don't need formatting, don't copy paste XD